# How to pass variables to a dynamically created javascript onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an onclick event that updates the values of a bootstrap modal element with results from a MySQL ajax query:

```
function UpdateModal($id){
  document.getElementById("modal_id").value=$id;
}

$results = GetMySQLResults();

button.onclick = function(){

        UpdateModal($results[0]["id"]);

}
```

However the problem is it always says "$result" is undefined when I click the button.

Is there a way to solve this without me having to dynamically create a modal?

Comment: what is `$i`? that could be your problem

Comment: And what's $results - assuming GetMySQLResults actually returns anything

Comment: And is `GetMySQLResults` asynchronous? I bet it is and it's the source of the problem!

Comment: whrs the code fr GetMySQLResults

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir eventhough it is async, how it will affect everytime as your button click event is not async. he specifically mention that everytime he get the error. I don't think async will take hrs to get response. Source is  spell mistake, see my ans.

Comment: @CBroe he has made spell mistake I suppose, see my ans

Comment: I have a lot of code and didn't want to include it all. Results returns a couple of rows, which I use to generate buttons dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: The problem is I can't pass values from the results to the button onclick function, since when the user clicks it. It says "undefined".

Comment: there could me multiple reasons, may be your $results and button click is not into same scope.. consider posting your js code atleast or try creating fiddle to help you better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. The problem was that $i wasn't declared and even if it was, it was updated to the last $i value, not the iteration. Also the problem was that $results wasn't declared globally.

To solve this I did the following:

```
var $globalResults;

...
{
   button.id = $i;

   button.onclick = function(event){
   var $j = event.currentTarget.id;
      UpdateModal($globalResult[$j]["id"]);
   }
}
```

Comment: thats what my comment refers to regarding scope of declaration of your variables and function... consider upvote if it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look..

```
$results = GetMySQLResults(); // You are collecting results into $results 

button.onclick = function(){

  UpdateModal($result[$i]["id"]); // You are sending parameter from $result 

}
```

Change your parameter as

```
 UpdateModal($results[$i]["id"]);
```

so basically you are not collecting any results into $result, that is the reason why you get the error..

basically a spell mistake `$results` has actual value (assuming GetMySQLResults()) returns value, and UpdateModal has parameter `$result` which is undefined..

Comment: He added the 's' to $result to make it $results. I had to read it trice as well to notice.

Comment: did't it clear from my comments I added into code block and on the statement below ... lol :)

Comment: Results has information. The problem is that when the user clicks on the button it says that "results[$i]" is undefined.

Comment: @ClemsonCoder looks like you have edited the post, previously it was $result. Nevermind, consider posting your full JS function...